# Sencha Touch 2: How long is app cached on iPhone?

Tags: caching, sencha-touch-2.1

I added a Sencha Touch 2 application to my homescreen and updated it afterwards on the server; but only the ajax-calls are sent, my changes to the sencha touch app itself aren't on my device.

How long does it take? Can I set the duration somewhere? Or is the app never downloaded again? But I can't imagine that I always have to reinstall the app after I changed something...

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you load the application, you can load it with caching on or off (set with loader)

also you can use CACHE MANIFEST files to cache an app indefinitely.

Comment: is this documented somewhere?